# Spring MVC jackson exception handling

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

Can I handle Jackson `UnrecognizedPropertyException` for a `@RequestBody` parameter? How can I configure this?

I'm working on a spring MVC project, and I use jackson as json plugin. Any mis-spell of the field name in a json request will lead to a error page, which should be a json string consist of error message. I'm a newbie to spring, and I think this error handling can be done with some spring configuration, but failed after several attempts. Any help?

Here is my mvc configure:

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {     
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        return bean;
    }    
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }       
}
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Login", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes="application/json", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody AjaxResponse login(
    @RequestBody UserVO user, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //do something ...
}
```

Normal request json is:

```
{"Username":"123123", "Password":"s3cret"}
```

But if I send the following request:

```
{"Username":"123123", "pwd":"s3cret"}
```

which field name is mis-spell, then Spring catch this `UnrecognizedPropertyException`, and returned a error page, but I want to catch this exception and return a json string. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use @ExceptionHandler annotation. Some documentation about it: http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

```
@Controller
public class WebMvcConfig {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/Login", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes="application/json", produces = "application/json")
  public @ResponseBody AjaxResponse login(@RequestBody UserVO user, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //do something ...
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(UnrecognizedPropertyException.class)
  public void errorHandler() {
    // do something. e.g. customize error response
  }
}
```

Comment: And one could register a global exception handler using @ControllerAdvice as described in this post: http://www.journaldev.com/2651/spring-mvc-exception-handling-exceptionhandler-controlleradvice-handlerexceptionresolver-json-response-example

Comment: For some reason a global exception handler in a different class didn't work for me